# Is it possible to mass-save many lightning:recordEditForms with only ONE button?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

Im implementing an line item editor for the "Order" SObject and want give lightning:recordEditForm with lightning:inputField a try for this.

What I have so far is an edit for the order combined with an iteration over the line-items which works as expected:

```
<aura:attribute name="Order"        type="SObject"          default="{}" />
<aura:attribute name="OrderId"      type="String"    />
<aura:attribute name="Items"        type="SObject[]"        default="[]" />
<aura:if isTrue="{! !empty(v.ParentType) }">
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.OrderId}" objectApiName="Order">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
        <lightning:button class="elfOrderSaveButton slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Items}" var="item">
        <div>{!item.PricebookEntry.Name}({!item.Id})</div>
        <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!item.Id}" objectApiName="OrderItem">
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quantity" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="UnitPrice" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="TotalPrice" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description" />
            <div class="elfItemSaveButtonWrapper">
                <lightning:button class="elfItemSaveButton slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </aura:iteration>   
</aura:if>
```

This looks like

[image]

Now I don't want each line item to have it's own save-button but instead only ONE master-button which saves all the items at once.

I've tried

```
<lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" label="SAVE"     onclick="{! c.saveAll }"/>
```

and in the controller

```
saveAll         : function(cmp, evt, hlp) { 
    $('.elfItemSaveButton').click();        
},
```

Excuse my jquery - without the outcome would be the same: thanks to LockerService, I can't trigger the click-event on the buttons remotely (the are not available in the secure DOM).

Is there a way to submit the lightning:recordEditForm without using the button on the form itself but form the "outside"?

One approach would be to implement the jquery click in a child-compo with api < 39 to bypass LockerService but I'm wondering if this could be done in a less dramatic way?

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that submitting multiple lightning:recordEditForms will likely have severe performance implications. You might want to consider submitting the data to an ordinary AuraEnabled method instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can submit a `lightning:recordEditForm` programmatically. You can do so by retrieving the component via it's `aura:id` and calling the `submit` method.

e.g.

`component.find('editForm').submit()`

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/specification) are the supporting docs

Since you are using the forms in an iteration, you can give them all the same `aura:id` and your `component.find` call will return an array as opposed to an individual component.

Beware, in my experience, submitting the form this way does NOT fire an `onsubmit` handler if you have one defined.

Comment: this sounds very good and I will give it a try. thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: tested: works perfectly - and it's very FAST!! btw: do you have any idea on how to turn off the step-size for lightning:inputField? this is causing me a lot of trouble... if not, I will just ask a new question.

Comment: @Anotonio and @Uwe Heim, by reading this thread I can understand multi insert/update is possible with recordEditForm. Could you please see this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226508/multi-insert-with-recordeditform) which is very similar to this thread?. I have tried with programmatic way of submitting in the controller but got error saying `$controller$handleSubmit [component.find(...).submit is not a function]`.