# Multi Insert with recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-recordeditform

Is it possible to bulk insert a records using recordEditForm component?.

Here's the sample lightning component which I tried:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editFormAccount"  objectApiName="Account">       
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" style="min-width: 100px;">
                <thead >                            
                    <tr class="slds-no-hover">
                        <th>Account Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

The above component is inserting only the last record.
Then I read somewhere that we could actually make use of submit method in recordEditForm. Then added onsubmit event in recordEditForm and added a controller method to that. Here is the line I tried in controller:

```
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {    
     component.find('editFormAccount').submit();
}
```

but the result which I got is same. It is inserting only the last record not all the 3 records.
Is there any workaround?. I have a usecase where I need to bring Lookup styling, that is why am using recordEditForm.

**UPDATE:**

Tried the solution provided by @sfdcfox

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:iteration items="1,2,3" var="iterate">
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" objectApiName="Account">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:iteration>
<lightning:button aura:id="submit" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}" label="Save" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
```

Controller.js

```
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('submit firing');
    component.find("editForm").forEach(form => form.saveRecord(
        result => {
            // Figure out what happened
        })
                                                  );
}
```

Getting below error

> Action failed: c:AccountNewPage$controller$handleSubmit [form.saveRecord is not a function]
>   Failing descriptor: {c:AccountNewPage$controller$handleSubmit}

Comment: if i understand correctly, in your form, you are trying to create 3 accounts after entering only the name for each? Not sure this would be the best use case for the lightning:recordEditForm. Instead, why not have the user create 3 accounts separately?

Comment: The actual use case is, I need to build a page where I should show 3 rows initially to enter child items for the parent. Very similar to MultiLine insert/update.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen I ran into the same problem. only the last record is getting saved out of bulk. Were you able to solve this?