# Multiple lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I have a quick way of entering multiple records where user can add rows(record) to add. I am using lightning:recordEditForm component in aura:iteration. When i add multiple rows everything is working just fine. However, when I use only one row to enter it gives me error

```
$controller$save [component.find(...).forEach is not a function]
```

This happens only if there is one record to add. Now if I use component.find('editForm'.submit(); I can enter one record but it is not working for multiple records.

My lightning cmp:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.venList}" var="ven" indexVar="index">
                        <tr>
                        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Vendor_Invoice__c" aura:id="editForm" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
                            <lightning:messages />
                            <td>
                                {!index + 1}
                           </td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Vendor_Name__c" />
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_2-of-12" fieldName="Name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Bill_Cycle__c" />
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Vendor_Customer_Service_Number__c" />
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                 <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Vendor_Repair_Number__c" />
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                 <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Last_Download__c" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                  <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Initial_Bill_Date__c" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                 <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Online_Access__c" />
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                 <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="X180_Monitored__c" />
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                 <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Location_Name__c" />
                             </td>
                            <td>
                                 <lightning:inputField class="slds-size_1-of-12" fieldName="Location_Address__c" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="display :none">
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c" value="{!v.recordId}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a onclick="{!c.removeRow}" data-record="{!index}">
                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:delete" size="small" alternativeText="Delete"/>
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete</span>
                                </a>
                            </td> 
                            </lightning:recordEditForm>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
```

Javascript Controller

```
 save: function(component, event, helper) {

         component.find("editForm").forEach(form => form.submit());  
  }
```

I have tried the following solutions:
[Is it possible to mass-save many lightning:recordEditForms with only ONE button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217482/is-it-possible-to-mass-save-many-lightningrecordeditforms-with-only-one-button?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Multi Insert with recordEditForm](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226508/multi-insert-with-recordeditform)

I cannot understand why it is giving this error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, that happens because [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is an Array method, hence the error `forEach is not a function`.

`component.find`, returns an Array-like collection, but not an array in which you can invoke the forEach method.

> find() returns different types depending on the result.
>
> - If the local ID is unique, find() returns the component.
> - If there are multiple components with the same local ID, find() returns an array of the components.
> - If there is no matching local ID, find() returns undefined.

I went ahead, and added multiple forms on a lgnt component and successfully created multiple records by iterating, I did not however, create my recordEditforms dynamically within an aura iteration.

the only difference I spot at this time are the missing braces in your function:

```
component.find("editForm").forEach( form =>{
        form.submit();

    })
```

Comment: is there a way around where it will work with adding single record as well?

Comment: I have tried component.find('editfor').array.prototype.forEach(); however, it is saying prototype is not a function

Comment: according to the link that you listed, it says that it can be parsed to array with that notation. i am very new to this so that is why I am trying to understand how this works

Comment: it states "Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate over it with forEach(). It can also be converted to a real Array using Array.from().However, some older browsers have not implemented NodeList.forEach() nor Array.from(). This can be circumvented by using Array.prototype.forEach() ". Since I am using IE browser i tried Array.prototype.forEach()

Comment: the original document that you linked about NodeList was more informative. I dont understand how to use HTML Collection, all I understood that it is a generic collection type like array. But sticking to your original comment, that component.find returns nodelist, I tried doing "var arr = Array(component.find('editForm'));
         arr.forEach(form => form.submit());"

Comment: Ok so could please guide me how I go about handling this type of issue?

Comment: the original document that you linked about NodeList was more informative. I dont understand how to use HTML Collection, all I understood that it is a generic collection type like array. But sticking to your original comment, that component.find returns nodelist, I tried doing "var arr = Array(component.find('editForm')); arr.forEach(form => form.submit());"  it gives error "form.submit is not a function" it says the same for saveRecord

Comment: I went ahead and tested in my own component - I am able to iterate over multiple recordEdit forms and submit them successfully =/

Comment: .forEach( form => { form.submit(); })   ?

Comment: I was able to do it for multiple forms but it was not working for single form. That concat function worked perfectly. But I really appreciate the time you took out to explain it to me. I wanted to give best answer to you AND @itzmukeshy7. I booked marked your links for future use.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick which is very much hidden in the documentation highlighted by [@glls](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/31663/glls) already in the [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256390/29734).

Here is what the documentation says:
[image: find documentation]

So we can handle this with [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method of [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
var editForms = c.find('editForm');
var forms = [].concat(editForms || []);
/* Now here the forms will always be an array, and won't break your code anymore. */

forms.forEach((form)=>{ 
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: That makes alot of sense. Thanks a lot! Just to understand it better. If we have multiple component of same name and want to do something action e.g. sum all the components then can we do form => form.sum(forms)?

Comment: @NikhilPrashar Hi Nikhil were u able to solve this? This is saving only the last record but not all the records.