# Editing fields before submitting for multiple lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform

I am trying to create a page so that I can **create multiple sObject records** in a single button click, **with the help of lightning:recordEditForm component**.

I checked the below link, and looks like this might work.
[Multiple lightning:recordEditForm](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256385/multiple-lightningrecordeditform)

The issue is that before submitting the form, I want to edit the values for each of the record. So

1. Is there any way to access the field values, update it and then submit?
2. OR is there any way to send this data to an Apex Controller where I can edit records before saving?

This is how my code looks:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="prod">
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" objectApiName="OrderItem">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

        <lightning:messages/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quantity"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="PaymentTerms__c"/>
    </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:iteration>

<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Next" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}"/>
```

And this is the controller method:

```
handleSubmit: function (component, event, helper) {
    const editForms = component.find('recordEditForm');
    const forms = [].concat(editForms || []);
    forms.forEach((form)=>{
        // Retrieve the field values, update it
        // ...
        // ...
        form.submit();
    });
},
```

I checked this post below by Alba Rivas; she is manipulating the field values on submit controller method of lightning:recordEditForm. I just need this capability, but in my own defined controller method.
https://albasfdc.com/2018/03/19/creating-pre-populated-records-with-lightningrecordeditform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way to access the field values, update it and then submit?

Yes (not really a good approach IMO, but it works). The idea is to access the input fields directly, instead of trying to access the fields thru record edit form.

Introduce `aura:id` for all the input fields. For example, `<lightning:inputField aura:id="qtyInputFld" fieldName="Quantity"/>`.

The controller JS method should be as shown below. This snippet shows the field update for only one field and I've used `forEach` just to illustrate how the field can be accessed, In your case, you should write the code for all fields and if you need to update only specific records, you would need to use other JS methods like `map`. Note that the order in which the `inputField` component instances are retrieved by this code will same as the order in which they are displayed in the UI.

```
handleSubmit: function (component, event, helper) {
    // Retrieve the fields and update them
    component.find('qtyInputFld').forEach(field => {
        // field.get('v.value') will get you the current field value
        field.set('v.value', '<Replace the value here>');
    }); 
    
    // Field updates made in the above code will persist in the component.
    // Now, you can call submit method on each instance of recordEditForm
    const editForms = component.find('recordEditForm');
    const forms = [].concat(editForms || []);
    forms.forEach((form)=>{
        form.submit();
    });
}
```

If you prefer better control over the manipulating the fields, then you should consider either of these approaches:

- Write custom JS method [*to access the fields, construct an array (or objects) using the accessed fields, replicate the changes back into the component etc.*] using the similar code as shown above.
- Write an apex class to perform DML and get rid of the `submit` method (of `recordEditForm`) in the controller JS. Construct an array or object or string (using the field values) and pass it to the apex method.

> 2. OR is there any way to send this data to an Apex Controller where I can edit records before saving?

If you want to pass the data to a custom apex class, then YES (as mentioned earlier). But if you want to use `submit` method of the `recordEditForm`, then the answer is NO. Because by using this method, you are delegating the task to lightning data service. I don't think Salesforce has provided any way to intercept this call.

***Additional Info:***

- If you look into the details of the proxy object `editForms` in your current code and try to hack into it, you may find some other approach to access the field values. But, I feel that it will not be worth the time (for this given requirement). Besides, this proxy object is deeply nested and not sure if Salesforce updates in future would change the proxy object structure (*in terms of both deprecating existing methods/ entries as well as introducing new ones*).
- You cannot use the `onchange` handler on the `inputField` because setting the values of the field using this handler works only during loading and before the user has entered any value into the field. After the user enters a value in the field, updating the field value doesn't work (but accessing the field value work). This info can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation).

Comment: I need to use recordEditForm, reason being that there are many fields, some of them even have picklist. Creating a form from scratch will involve lot of time.
Yes, I tried to look into the proxy object (form), but couldn't find anything. :(

Comment: This approach works with recordEditForm (in case, it wasn't clear from my answer). Its just that instead of access the the fields via the instance of recordEditForm, you would be accessing the inputField instances directly.

Comment: yes, I understood. I am already working on it.

Answer (score -1):

please use following way to modify fields before submitting record edit form.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
 aura:id="myform"
 objectApiName="Object__c" 
 onsubmit="{!c.onRecordSubmit}" 
 onsuccess="{!c.onRecordSuccess}">
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" type="submit" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

JS Controller

```
onRecordSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
  var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
  eventFields["Name"] = "Test Name";
  component.find('myform').submit(eventFields);
},
```

Comment: There are multiple recordEditForm components. This won't work.